# How to integrate Stockfish in Html with chess.js and chessboard.js?

Tags: javascript, html, chess, chessboard.js, stockfish

It is just a fun project but I could not get the Stockfish to give a move after my move.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Chessboard.js Example - Stockfish vs Human</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chessboard.css">
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .highlight-white {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px rgb(181, 243, 181);
    }

    .highlight-black {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px rgb(62, 177, 192);
    }
</style>
<div id="myBoard" style="width: 400px"></div>

<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script src="chessboard.js"></script>
<script src="chess.js"></script>
<script src="stockfish.js"></script> <!-- Include the Stockfish JavaScript file -->

<script>
    var board = null;
    var $board = $('#myBoard');
    var game = new Chess();
    var squareToHighlight = null;
    var squareClass = 'square-55d63';
    var stockfish;

    function removeHighlights(color) {
        $board.find('.' + squareClass).removeClass('highlight-' + color);
    }

    function onDragStart(source, piece, position, orientation) {
        // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
        if (game.game_over()) return false;

        // only pick up pieces for White
        if (piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) return false;
    }

    // Initialize Stockfish
    stockfish = new Worker('stockfish.js');
    stockfish.postMessage('uci');
    stockfish.postMessage('isready');
    stockfish.postMessage('ucinewgame');

    function makeStockfishMove() {
        stockfish.postMessage('position fen ' + game.fen());
        stockfish.postMessage('go depth 5');
    }

    // Handle Stockfish's response
    stockfish.onmessage = function (event) {
        var line = event.data;
        if (line.startsWith('bestmove')) {
            var move = line.match(/bestmove (.+)/)[1];
            game.ugly_move(move);
            board.position(game.fen());

            // Highlight the opponent's move
            removeHighlights('black');
            squareToHighlight = move.substring(0, 2);
            $board.find('.square-' + squareToHighlight).addClass('highlight-black');

            // Check if the game is over
            if (game.game_over()) {
                alert('Game over');
            }
        }
    };

    function onDrop(source, target) {
        // see if the move is legal
        var move = game.move({
            from: source,
            to: target,
            promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
        });

        // illegal move
        if (move === null) return 'snapback';

        // highlight white's move
        removeHighlights('white');
        $board.find('.square-' + source).addClass('highlight-white');
        $board.find('.square-' + target).addClass('highlight-white');

        // Make Stockfish move after a short delay
        window.setTimeout(makeStockfishMove, 250);
    }

    function onMoveEnd() {
        $board.find('.square-' + squareToHighlight).addClass('highlight-black');
    }

    // update the board position after the piece snap
    // for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
    function onSnapEnd() {
        board.position(game.fen());
    }

    var config = {
        draggable: true,
        position: 'start',
        onDragStart: onDragStart,
        onDrop: onDrop,
        onMoveEnd: onMoveEnd,
        onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
    };
    board = Chessboard('myBoard', config);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If it were correct I would be likely be defeated in the match, but it would not even give a move. I have used `chess.js`, `chessboard.js` in addition to the `stockfish.js` file. I want this code to at least run and later defeat me.

The picture is when I ran this code. The first move is always me for now. Asking someone of expertise to help me in this.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Without the various javascript code we cannot try to replicate your app nor see the error - are there errors reported in the console?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Ther are cdns and unpkgs;

Chess.js= [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js)

Chessboard.js= [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chessboard-js/1.0.0/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js)  and Chessboard.css= [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chessboard-js/1.0.0/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css)

Stockfish.js= [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stockfish.js/10.0.2/stockfish.min.js)

jQuery = [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js)